# MSSQL Export Binary DateTime to MySql DateTime

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, datetime, database-migration

I generated scripts from Microsoft Sql Server (MSSQL) and the datetime fields had binary values.  I have altered the scripts to import into MySQL, but I cannot figure out how to convert those binary values to MySQL datetime values.

Here is an example of a binary datetime value:  0x0000988100DCD865

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this....

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(19) ,CONVERT(DATETIME ,  0x0000988100DCD865),121)

RESULT:  2006-11-22 13:24:04      --<-- this is MySql Datetime Compliant
```

Comment: I should have clarified that these binary values are now in a MySQL database.  Is there a similar script that convert a binary value in MySQL to a datetime value in MySQL?